# angular 2 conditionally show or hide components

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 buttons and 3 components, What I want is, initially, only the first element visible. Clicking the buttons will show relevant component and hide the not relevant. How would you do that?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Parent',
    template: `
        <div class="tab">
            <span class="btn">show child 1</span>
            <span class="btn">show child 2</span>
            <span class="btn">show child 3</span>
        </div>
        <Child1></Child1>
        <Child2></Child2>
        <Child3></Child3>
    `,
})
export class ParentComponent  {
}
```

Comment: This plunker will give you a good understanding https://embed.plnkr.co/NzMrJixtwZv0l2ohiZgQ/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Parent',
    template: `
        <div class="tab">
            <span (click)="show('show1')" class="btn">show child 1</span>
            <span (click)="show('show2')" class="btn">show child 2</span>
            <span (click)="show('show3')" class="btn">show child 3</span>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="show1"><Child1></Child1></div>
        <div *ngIf="show2"><Child2></Child2></div>
        <div *ngIf="show3"><Child3></Child3></div>
    `
})


export class ParentComponent  {
    public show1 = true;
    public show2 = false;
    public show3 = false;

    show(tab){
        this.show1 = false;
        this.show2 = false;
        this.show3 = false;

        console.log(tab)
        if(tab == 'show1') {
            this.show1 = true
        }
        if(tab == 'show2') {
            this.show2 = true
        }
        if(tab == 'show3') {
            this.show3 = true
        }
    }
}
```

Very crude form. Optimise the code as you like.
But, hope you got the idea.

Comment: Why Downvote ? according to question seems answer is correct

Comment: Downvoter, please try to explain or give a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The first option is I will say its better to use lazy loading to solve this problem. [Angular Lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

If you don't want to use lazy loading and want to follow the answer from Ajey, you may follow this way to write less code

```
  @Component({
  selector: "Parent",
  template: `
    <div class="tab">
      <span (click)="curStep = 'step1'" class="btn">show child 1</span>
      <span (click)="curStep = 'step2'" class="btn">show child 2</span>
      <span (click)="curStep = 'step3'" class="btn">show child 3</span>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="curStep == 'step1'"><child1></child1></div>
    <div *ngIf="curStep == 'step2'"><child2></child2></div>
    <div *ngIf="curStep == 'step3'"><child3></child3></div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
    curStep: string = "step1";
}
```